# How to enumerate list of users via SQL?

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird2.5

I am creating a simple tool for managing database users for our product, with basic CRUD operations. The tool is built in VS2013 using the Firebird ADO v5.5.5.0 connection against a Firebird 2.5 database.

Is there a way of using SQL to enumerate the list of users?

I need to display the list of users, and then perform CRUD operations on that list.

Running a command such as

```
SELECT RDB$USER
FROM RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES
GROUP BY 1
```

as shown in [this link here](http://firebird-support.yahoogroups.narkive.com/j1n6s1IC/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-firebird-db-users) isn't adequate as it requires that user privileges exist in this table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird 2.5 or earlier, the only way to access the list of all users is through the service API. The Firebird ADO.net provider has a utility class for this: `FirebirdSql.Data.Services.FbSecurity`:

```
var fbSecurity = new FbSecurity(ConnectionString);
var users = fbSecurity.DisplayUsers();
foreach (var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);
}
```

You can also use this class to add, delete or modify users.

Note that for most users, this is restricted to that user alone, only SYSDBA and users with role RDB$ADMIN are allowed to see all users.

Note that Firebird 3 deprecated the services API for user management, and from Firebird 3 on you should use the SQL user management statements. See [SQL Features for Managing Access](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-access-sql.html).

Firebird 3 also added the [virtual table `SEC$USERS`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-pseudo-users.html) with the users that the current user is allowed to manage. For most users, this is usually only that user, only SYSDBA and users with role RDB$ADMIN are allowed to see all users.

Be aware that Firebird 3 can have multiple authentication plugins, which means that usernames can occur multiple times (ie at most once per plugin).